# run cloudflare tunnel and postgres on docker network, expose db to public

Tags: postgresql, docker, cloudflare

I started my container using this

`docker run --network my-network cloudflare/cloudflared:latest tunnel --no-autoupdate run --token eyxxxxxxxx`

then postgres

`docker run -d --name qu-postgres --network my-network -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=QuDb -p 5439:5432 -v /desktop/PGDbMount/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres`

Setup the in the cloudflare ui
Subdomain: db
Domain: my-domain
Path: -
Type: TCP
URL: qu-postgres:5432

I managed to connect to localhost:5439 and 192.168.x.x:5439 but when I type
host: db.my-domain.com
port: 5439
username+password+dbname

it failed.

I am not sure which step did I miss. I have other containers of webapis and they are accessible via xxx.my-domain.com, so the cloudflare tunnel is definitely working